# Function: The Surface Area of a Sphere

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm really having trouble trying to figure out a function.

So, the surface area $S$ of a sphere is a function of its radius $r$ given by $S(r) = 4\pi r^2$. I'm trying to find $S(2)$ and $S(3)$.

Am I supposed to plug in $2$ and $3$ respectively for $r$? Silly question perhaps, but I'm confused. :(

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what you’re supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S(r)=4\pi r^2$$
$$S(t)=4\pi t^2$$
$$S(\text{bananas})=4\pi (\text{bananas})^2$$
$$S(2)=4\pi(2)^2$$
$$S(3)=4\pi(3)^2$$

Keep in mind you can't actually square literal bananas, but you could call a variable "bananas" and this would work. $S$ represents what we *do* to the input, regardless of what the input is.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. "r" is nothing more than an independent variable. In this case, it represents the radius of your sphere. For your purposes, think of a function as a machine that has both input and output. If you are looking for the surface area of a sphere with radius r, then "feed" r into your function, S, and out pops the surface area. This works for all r > 0.

Comment: Works for $r=0$, too. :-)